# connect Java Spark Sql to Mysql

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing this issue that I am not able to resolve. I am writing a javaspark code with MySQL integration. I can see there is a small fix to this.

```
package JavaSpark.Javs.SQL;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


public class sparkSqlMysql {


private static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOGGER = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(sparkSqlMysql.class);

private static final String MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BCG";
private static final String MYSQL_USERNAME = "root";
private static final String MYSQL_PWD = "mypassword";

private static final SparkSession sparkSession =
        SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Spark2JdbcDs").getOrCreate();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //JDBC connection properties
    final Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
    connectionProperties.put("user", MYSQL_USERNAME);
    connectionProperties.put("password", MYSQL_PWD);
    connectionProperties.put("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    final String dbTable =
            "select * from testLoad";
     // Load MySQL query result as Dataset
    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF =
            sparkSession.read()
                    .jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, dbTable, connectionProperties);
  }
}
```

When I execute this gives me an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`dbTable` should simply be table name, not the query.

```
    final String dbTable = "testLoad";
    Dataset<Row> jdbcDF =
            sparkSession.read()
                    .jdbc(MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL, dbTable, connectionProperties);
    jdbcDF.show(); // just for testing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query wrapped in parenthesis and aliased:

```
final String dbTable = "(select * from testLoad) t";
```

You can also use the table name in the variable `dbTable`, as said in the other answer.